# How to Get a list of All Asset Types?

Tags: marketing-cloud, content-builder, asset

I need to get a list of all Asset Types. I know that the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/base-asset-types.htm) has a list of all asset types, but I wonder if there is any API method that I can use to get this list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as the asset route documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/content-api.htm), but with `asset/v1/assetTypes`

When in doubt for a route, check the MC applications in your network tab! They use those routes themselves.

Comment: Wow! thanks AsinusAsinumFricat, that defiantly worked. I guess there are many undocumented API functions out there that needs to be found.